# Synonymize [ArumentException] and [System.ArgumentException] (and possibly illegalargumentexception and invalidargumentexception)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Per the tag wiki, [argumentexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argumentexception) (119 questions) is

> ... a specific exception in the .NET framework thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.

Thus, it's referring to the .NET ArgumentException, which is [system.argumentexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.argumentexception) (32 questions).  Those two tags are the exact same thing, and should be merged (I'm not sure which way though, but since [argumentexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argumentexception) has more questions, I would say that it should be the receiving tag).

There's also [illegalargumentexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/illegalargumentexception) (401 questions), which is the java equivalent, and [invalidargumentexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invalidargumentexception) (20 questions), which (at least from what I can tell) is the iOS equivalent.  These two might be left alone since they are from different languages, but they might also be merged since they are the same concepts.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see where the issue is in my proposal.  I'm saying that [tag:argumentexception] should receive the questions from [tag:system.argumentexception] (perhaps they should instead be retagged?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the burnination route, so I edited, voted and cleaned up the 40 questions with that tag and either removed the tag or replaced it with [argumentexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argumentexception).

The tag is now without questions. If it remains that way till 03:00 UTC the tag will be removed. Pr0blam solved.